# What format is UserProfile_GUID?

Tags: user-profile, ldap, php

**LATER EDIT: UserProfile_GUID has nothing to do with objectguid in LDAP. However, it can be used as DN like this `dn=<GUID={the_string}` when you bind to LDAP. UserProfile_GUID and objectguid are different things**

I want to send the current user's `UserProfile_GUID` to a php script that searches the LDAP server by the `objectguid` property, giving me the user's name.

The problem is `bin2hex(objectguid)` in php returns a different value from the `UserProfile_GUID` that's showing in Sharepoint.

*So what format is `UserProfile_GUID` in Sharepoint?* How can I use it to search the LDAP server?

`UserProfile_GUID` in Sharepoint is something like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

**LATER EDIT: Is there any way I can find some common ID between Sharepoint user propreties and php LDAP? So I can use it to validate the user from Sharepoint to php**

Comment: Hi there, I'm not sure if the UserProfile GUID will match the LDAP object guid you are looking for? Have you checked manually whether passing user profile GUID returns appropriate user name?

Comment: I am trying but I cannot search the LDAP tree using the UserProgile GUID because it's not in the right format, it's actually a Binding String and I need a hex value

Comment: I am pretty convinced that the Guid you see in SharePoint isn't related in any way to the actual id the object has on AD. See [here](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.it/2011/04/ad-attributes-used-in-standard.html) for more details, but I would first try to ensure that the id you have at hand actually represent the same info you need to access the AD entry.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I found out that the guid given in Sharepoint is actually used as DN at binding, but my AD doesn't allow search when I bind without credentials. So yes, you're right, that string from sharepoint is not useful.

Comment: So, for future reference, you confirm that the guid in SharePoint isn't actually related to the AD item in anyway? Good to know that those info where right

Comment: @SPArchaeologist you're right, I just added the specification at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Do you need to use this approach? You should be able to get the samAccountName from the profile service as well.

Comment: @Bunzab yes but I want to authenticate the user in php by using some kind of id, some kind of hash, not by the user's name. I wanted to take this uid and send it within a link to my php login page, which had to search the AD for the id and return the username.

Answer (score 3):

The ObjectGUID is a binary string ( or octet string ), so what you are probably seeing is some random nonsense characters when you attempt display the value.

The ObjectGUID actually follows a well-established standard - it's a UUID version 4. With this information, you should be able to decode the binary string into a readable string representation.

Take a look at this [implementation](https://github.com/Alaneor/AD-X/blob/master/ADX/Core/Converter.php#L263) of the conversion in php.

Here's the function in question. It expects the $guid in its original binary form as returned from server.

```
function _to_p_guid( $guid )
{
$hex_guid = unpack( "H*hex", $guid );
$hex    = $hex_guid["hex"];

$hex1   = substr( $hex, -26, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -28, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -30, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -32, 2 );
$hex2   = substr( $hex, -22, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -24, 2 );
$hex3   = substr( $hex, -18, 2 ) . substr( $hex, -20, 2 );
$hex4   = substr( $hex, -16, 4 );
$hex5   = substr( $hex, -12, 12 );

$guid = $hex1 . "-" . $hex2 . "-" . $hex3 . "-" . $hex4 . "-" . $hex5;

return $guid;
}
```

---

2. Other Approach

All you need to do when retrieving the objectguid is convert it to hex with

```
$hex_guid = bin2hex($binary_guid);
```

then to get it into a format to query the active directory there needs to be an escape character every 2 characters like:

4e\7c\70\75\e7\ac\e4\44\af\00\b1\16\28\39\25\7b

here's the function to use:

```
function FormatGUID($hexGUID){

        $hexGUID = str_replace("-", "", $hexGUID);

        for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($hexGUID)-2; $i = $i+2){

            $output .=  "\\".substr($hexGUID, $i, 2);
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

I've not tested this very much yet though, so beware!